Solve $x^2<4$. How do I calculate for negative $x$?

Solve $x^2<4$

From inspection, obviously the answer is $-2<x<2$.
But I'm not sure how to actually write it down step by step.
$\sqrt{x^2}=\pm x$
If $x>0 \Rightarrow x^2<4 \Rightarrow x<2 \Rightarrow 0<x<2$
If $x<0 \Rightarrow x^2<4 \Rightarrow \sqrt{x^2}<\sqrt{4} \Rightarrow x>2$ The inequality sign flipped because $x<0$. But then I get a contradiction: $x<0$ and $x>2$.
So I only know how to calculate the positive $x$ and not the negative, resulting in only $0<x<2$.

$\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$ so we have $|x|<2$.

I don't understand all the downvotes. This is something that we expect students to be able to do, but I don't think it's often taught what the rigorous logic is.

@lulu It take a lot more than that to get a rigorous answer.

This question is similar to: Simplifying inequality contradicts actual inequality.

Let $x<0$ this implies that $-x>0$ so...
$$ (-x)^2 < 4 \implies -x < 2 \implies x>-2 $$ My bad, did not realize there was a contradiction in the way I did it before, this should be right though.

$$x^2<4$$
$$x^2-4<0$$
$$(x-2)(x+2)<0$$
Since $(x-2)(x+2)$ is positive, it must be the case that one factor is positive and the other is negative.
So we have that one the following is true:
(1) $x-2<0$ and $x+2>0$
(2) $x-2>0$ and $x+2<0$
Working through (1), if $x-2<0$, then $x<2$, and if $x+2>0$, then $x>-2$. So this gets us $-2<x<2$.
Working through (2), we get $x>2$ and $x<-2$, and it's impossible for both of those to be correct, so we're left with just the solutions from (1).
We can also take the square root of both sides. In doing so, we're taking the inverse of squaring. With an inequality, you can apply the same function, or the inverse of the same function, to both sides, but only if it's an increasing function. If it's a decreasing function, you have to flip the inequality. $x \rightarrow x^2$ is increasing for $x>0$ and decreasing for $x<0$, so we have that either $x$ is positive, and $\sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt{4}$ or $x$ is negative, and $\sqrt{x^2} > \sqrt{4}$. The first case gives us $0<x<2$. In the second case, if $x$ is negative, then $\sqrt{x^2}$ is $-x$, so we get $-x>2$, or $x>-2$. Combined with $x$ being negative, we have $-2<x<0$. So we have $0<x<2$ or $-2x<0$, and by inspection $0$ is also a solution, so putting all of that together we have $-2<x<2$.

When needed, I usually write step-by-step solution like this:
$$ x^2 < 4 \\\\ \implies |x|^2<2^2~~~~~~ \\\\ \implies |x|<2~~~~~~~~~\\\\ \implies-2<x<2~~\\\\ \implies\boxed{\bf x\in(-2, 2)}$$
Just replace $x$ with $|x|$ and there will be no problem solving this inequality for negative $x$.
